# Box shadow animation

Tags: html, css

I was wondering why the box-shadow isn't working the other way around. Is it possible to make it go the other way as where it spreads from the center of the button?

Thanks

```css
.slide {
  -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
  transition: ease-out 0.3s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #000;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
}

.slide_inside:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #000;
  background: initial;
}

.slide_outside:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 -50px #000;
  background: initial;
}
```

```html
<h6>Inside</h6>
<a href="#">
  <button class="slide slide_inside">Button</button>
</a>
<h6>Outside</h6>
<a href="#o">
  <button class="slide slide_outside">Button</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the shadow to go outside you need to remove inset, that implies the outset that's why there's no `outset` keyword, and as you know you can't transition a property from nothing to something you'll have to have an initial value, that's why we start with none for the outset/inset.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.slide {
  -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
  transition: ease-out 0.3s;
  box-shadow: none 0 0 0 0 #000;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
}

.slide_inside:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #000;
  background: initial;
}

.slide_outside:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px #000;
  background: initial;
}
```

```html
<h6>Inside</h6>
<a href="#">
  <button class="slide slide_inside">Button</button>
</a>
<h6>Outside</h6>
<a href="#o">
  <button class="slide slide_outside">Button</button>
</a>
```

Comment: I see, thank you! What would be the best way to create the effect where as the fill starts from the center and then spreads?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple `box-shadow` if you want to have an inside that become and outside shadow

```css
.slide {
  transition: linear 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 30px #000,
     0 0 0 0px #000;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
  margin:50px;
  color:#fff;
}


.slide_outside:hover {
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 0px #000,
    0 0 0 30px #000;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<h6>Outside</h6>
<a href="#o">
  <button class="slide slide_outside">Button</button>
</a>
```